# Iterating through a multidimensional Javascript array filled with Google Maps markers objects

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops, google-maps-api-3, each

I store all of the Google Maps marker objects in a single array. Right now I am trying to set up a function that will delete all of the markers in the array from the map, but I'm having trouble with the loop.

First, I put each marker in an array like so:

```
eval("markerZip"+value.zip+" = new google.maps.Marker({map: map, icon: '/images/mapmarker.php?m=zip_marker.png', position: zipCenter});");
eval("markersArray['markerZip"+value.zip+"'] =  markerZip"+value.zip);
```

Then when I want to delete the markers I do this:

```
function removeAllMarkers(exceptId) {
    $.each(markersArray, function(index, value) {
        if(value != exceptId) {
            value.setMap(null);
            console.log(value);
        }
    });
}
```

However, iterating through the array doesn't seem to be doing anything. It's as if the array is empty because the console.log line returns nothing. When I display the array in my console, it shows "[]" (which I then click to display the child objects) which contains:

```
markerZip01002
    U { gm_accessors_={...}, map=U, b=U, more...}

markerZip02111
    U { gm_accessors_={...}, map=U, b=U, more...}

markerZip02135
    U { gm_accessors_={...}, map=U, b=U, more...}

markerZip02139
    U { gm_accessors_={...}, map=U, b=U, more...}

markerZip02466
    U { gm_accessors_={...}, map=U, b=U, more...}
```

Comment: Why are you using `eval()` instead of just writing the appropriate javascript code?

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that you are using an array as a hash or dictionary.  jQuery checks to see if the object it has been passed has a `length` property - [see here](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/core.js#L606) for the implementation.  Since you are passing an array, it iterates over the values in the array which can be accessed via the integer keys between 0 and `obj.length - 1`.  Since there are no values in your array that can be accessed that way, the loop immediately terminates.

You are treating your `markersArray` as a JavaScript object rather than an array - so you'd be better off using `{}` rather than `[]` for your `markersArray` object.

`<rant>`In addition, there is no need to use `eval` for setting keys in a hash - ever. It is inefficient - you need to start up a new version of the JavaScript runtime for each invocation of `eval`.  It is fragile - you are writing strings that contain code and injecting other strings inside them - a misplaced `"` or `//` in your *data* can stop your program cold.  And finally, it requires continual use of the global scope - which should be avoided whenever you don't *own* the global scope.`</rant>`

You can replace these two lines:

```
eval("markerZip"+value.zip+" = new google.maps.Marker({map: map/*etc.*/});");
eval("markersArray['markerZip"+value.zip+"'] =  markerZip"+value.zip);
```

with this one line:

```
// Assume we did this earlier
// var markersHash = {};
markersHash["markerZip"+value.zip] = new google.maps.Marker({map: map /*etc.*/});
```

When you do that, your call to `$.each` will work as expected.